# Ship by address type

Tags: bigcommerce

I see there is a field under each customer address with Residential/Commercial as the options.

Is there any way to set up a shipping rule based on whether it is a residential or commercial address?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

address_type is an enum field of the [customer address object](https://developer.bigcommerce.com/api/objects/v2/customer_address) that can be set to residential or commercial. There is not built-in support for setting shipping rules on this via BC. You can use [ShipperHQ](https://support.bigcommerce.com/articles/Public/Setting-Up-ShipperHQ) to accomplish something similar.